# How can I obtain data from database with a specific DateTime range

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

I want to calculate statistics based for data from DB. For example:
In 2019 you earned: XXXX
In January 2019 you earned: XXXX
Till now you earned: XXXX
etc...

Are there any build in (sorting) functions in EF to do that?
How to build a proper method?

My controller so far:

```
[HttpGet("GetStatistics/{From}/{To}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetStatisticsByTime(DateTime From, DateTime To)
    {
      try
      {
        var guest = await _guestService.GetByTime(From, To);
        return Ok(guest);
      }
      catch (NullReferenceException e)
      {
        return NotFound("Can't found values in this time period");
      }
    }
```

My service and repository interface method declaration:

```
Task<IEnumerable<TEntity>> GetByTime(DateTime From, DateTime To);
```

And I should create an implementation of above

Edit1;
I've tried with "where" but I got null (In db exist values with year 2017, 2018).
I've changed controller for one attribute - int year, and my method is:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Guest>> GetByTime(int year)
    {
      var guests = await _bookingContext.Guests
        .Where(x => x.reservation.CheckOut.Year == year)
        .ToListAsync();

        return guests;
    }
```

But that gives me null

CheckOut is a field with DateTime type.

Comment: >= 1st Jan 2019 && < 1st Feb 2019 will get you all of the January data. As an example. This will be done in your `Where` clause.

Comment: Have a go at it, and then we can give you some specific advice. Show us your first attempt.

Comment: You'll want to do some research into [LINQ to Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/linq-to-entities). See also [Getting Started with LINQ in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I want to recommend you to use `CompareTo` method with `DateTime` type, which
 returns a signed number indicating the relative values of this instance and the value
    parameter. Value Description Less than zero This instance is earlier than value.
    Zero This instance is the same as value. Greater than zero This instance is later
    than value.

Answer (score 0):

Ok SOLVED.
I've done it with a proper method in service layer - it was a reason of null:

```
var guests = await _iGuestRepository.GetByTime(year);
      return guests.ToList();
```

I was using additional mappers, which caused a problem.
Repository layer:

```
var guests = await _bookingContext.Guests
        .Where(x => x.reservation.CheckOut.Year == year)
        .ToListAsync();

        return guests;
```

Comment: What SQL did that submit to your database?

Comment: From your original question, it sounded like you wanted a group by clause, but there is not one in your answer.  Did you end up using one, or are you hitting the database for each value you want?  Also, don't you need a sum to aggregate the amount earned?